# React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child State Array NextJS

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

What I'm trying to do is to make a GET request to a local server (Strapi) with axios.
I've created the base instance, imported it in the file that I want to use it and I'm having trouble with the state array.

The error that I'm getting on the frontend is: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Below is the code

```
state = {
    posts: [] 
}


componentDidMount() {
    API.get(`/posts`).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({ posts: res.data });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide your markup/JSX

Comment: And the whole component class, so we can know how best to help you

Comment: `export default class CaseStudies extends Component {
  state = {posts: []}

  componentDidMount() {
    API.get(`/posts`).then(res => {
      this.setState({ posts: res.data });
    });
  }

render() {
    return (
             <div className="container">
          <div className="row container-flex">
            {(this.state.posts || []).map((item, theIndex) => (
              <CaseStudyArticle key={theIndex} index={theIndex} post={item} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}`

Comment: Please provide definition of CaseStudyArticle, and possible the whole error message. You can add them to your question and see if they can be well formatted. I will run it on codesandbox and get you a feedback.

Comment: I simulated CaseStudyArticle definition and it works, so my best guess is that the error is from it. Here is a link https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-einstein-7uzxm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you, it was probably some problem by Prettier.